# How can I implement the count 60 seonds for hospital

Tags: java, netbeans

Who can help me to implement the function if the patient waiting for over 60 seconds the category will change from "low" to "high" and queue behind the newest patient category with "high". Can someone help to me to solve it?

EmergencyRoomSimulator1.java :

```
package emergencyroomsimulator1;

import java.util.Random;

public class EmergencyRoomSimulator1 {

         private static final int WAIT_LIMIT = 1000; // 1000 = 1 second 

private PatientQueue pq = new PatientQueue(); 

private void t() { 
    try {  Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(WAIT_LIMIT));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } 
} // end t method

private void patientArrives(Patient p) { 
    pq.registerPatient(p); 
    System.out.println(" ARRIVAL: " + p.getID()); 
    System.out.println(" time arrived: " + p.getTimeArrived()); 
    System.out.println(" category: " + p.getCategory()); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    t(); 
} // end patientArrives method

public void doctorVisits() { 
    Patient p = pq.getNextPatient(); 
    System.out.println(" VISIT: " + p.getID()); 
    System.out.println(" time arrived: " + p.getTimeArrived()); 
    System.out.println(" category: " + p.getCategory()); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    t(); 
} // end doctorVisits method

private void simulate() { 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    System.out.println("ER OPEN"); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(100, "high")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(101, "low")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(102, "low")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(103, "high")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(104, "high")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(105, "low")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(106, "low")); 
    patientArrives(new Patient(107, "high")); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits(); 
    doctorVisits();
        doctorVisits(); 

    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
    System.out.println("ER CLOSED"); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------"); 
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
      EmergencyRoomSimulator1 er = new EmergencyRoomSimulator1(); 
    er.simulate(); 
} // end main 

}
```

Patient.java :

```
package emergencyroomsimulator1;


import java.util.Date;



public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient> {
    protected int id;
protected String category;
protected Date timeArrived;

EmergencyRoomSimulator1 emg;
//protected Date CurrentTime;


// accessors and mutators

public int getID() {
    return id;   
}

public void setID(int idIn) {
    this.id = idIn;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String categoryIn) {
    this.category = categoryIn;
}

public java.util.Date getTimeArrived() {
    return timeArrived;
}



public int compareTo(Patient other) {
    // This code doesn't handle nulls
    int result = getCategory().compareTo(other.getCategory());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = getTimeArrived().compareTo(other.getTimeArrived());
    }
    return result;
}

// default constructor
public Patient() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.category = "low"; // unclassified Patients go to the end of the queue
    this.timeArrived = new Date();
}

// overloaded constructor
public Patient(int idIn, String categoryIn) {
    this.id = idIn;
    this.category = categoryIn;
    this.timeArrived = new Date();
}


}
```

PatientComparator.java:

```
package emergencyroomsimulator1;


import java.util.Comparator;


public class PatientComparator implements Comparator<Patient>{
    public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) {
       int result = p1.getCategory().compareTo(p2.getCategory());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = p1.getTimeArrived().compareTo(p2.getTimeArrived());
    }
    return result; 
    }
}
```

PatientQueue.java :

```
package emergencyroomsimulator1;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PatientQueue {
    PriorityQueue pq;

    // default constructor
    public PatientQueue() {
        this.pq = new PriorityQueue<Patient>(1, new PatientComparator());
    }

    public void registerPatient(Patient p) {
        this.pq.add(p);
    } // end registerPatient method

    public Patient getNextPatient() {
        return (Patient) this.pq.poll();
    } // end getNextPatient method

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Dont just drop requirements and code, and leave it to the readers to figure where exactly you are stuck. see [mcve] for further information how to do that.

Comment: So, what's "watching" the queue? I would "imagine" that when `getNextPatient` is called, it needs to assess all the patients in the queue and make determinations about if a patient's priority needs to change or not

Comment: yes if the patient category is "low" and waiting for over 60 second the category will change to "high"

Comment: @JohnLew, what part of your program switches patients from low to high priority when they are waiting to long?

Comment: I haven't implement the function because I try but it is fail, I need ur helpand I  use hardcode to set the set the patient with priority high or low